# Cant import libraries from Uniswap documentation example in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix, uniswap

I am looking how to implement liquidity pool from [UniSwap documentation](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/guides/providing-liquidity/setting-up) and getting error `not found: Deferred import` even when i just copy their example without any changes from my side i am getting the same error

i am trying to implement these :

```
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/libraries/TickMath.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/INonfungiblePositionManager.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/base/LiquidityManagement.sol';
```

Again..even when i copy their example i got error.I am using Remix ide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you import has to be done if you import via from your `node_modules`, in your case you should rather import directly from GitHub by including the link of the contract itself.

```
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/contracts/libraries/TickMath.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/INonfungiblePositionManager.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/libraries/TransferHelper.sol";
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/base/LiquidityManagement.sol";
```

for the `IERC721Receiver.sol` you need to find the right version to import or add directly to your remix and change the version.

Comment: But now i am getting not found @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Enumerable.sol error - BTW i am planing to use this contract to android platform using web3j,but i assume it doesn't matter which platform I plan to work on since it's a solidity code?

Comment: No it doesn't matter, solidity is for smart contract, then integration you can use what you want web3j, web3js, ethers.js, etc.
 `@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Enumerable.sol` you need to find the contract on github, and paste the link like I have shown you above.
If you are not able to find the right version just copy the contract into a new file on your remix and import it `import "./nameOfFile.sol";`

Comment: i dont know,i give up.I copied IERC721Enumerable.sol in new file in remix but then everything explode with errors.Because some imports needs 0.7.6 version of solidity,and some 0.8.0 and some betwen 0.5.0 and 0.8.0...and getting not found: Deferred import error....i would imagine that uniswap would make thing easier,so that peoples can use their docs for fast testing while learning.Thanks for your effort tho

Comment: I flattened all the interfaces and contracts, you can just copy/paste this code
https://gist.github.com/Aboudjem/886f9fae8649d3801b4ffe6e9bac1564

Comment: I dont know what to say..thank you a ton